# Foreach (or LOOP) number one by one PHP / LARAVEL

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a problem with Foreach number One by One.

Here is my problem, I have a variable, for example - $x = 5;
How I can Foreach this number in style - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (To original number)?

Answer (score 0):

Why your are not using a simple [for-loop](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.for.php)?

```
$x=5;

for ($i=1; $i=$x; $i++) {
    echo $i . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it. **(Laravel)**

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $room->host; $i++)
 <option>{{ $i }}</option>
@endfor
```

Comment: Laravel is a big framework, you should ask for a sample code using in a blade template.